# Record a gif from screen for Arch Linux

Tags: linux, screen-recording, gif

I'm looking for a program like Gyazo Gif which would let you select a portion of the screen, and record it to a gif. Gyazo does work on Linux, but only regular PNG, the gif is windows only.

Is there an alternative? What do you use?

- and is free

Comment: Gratis or Commercial?

Comment: @Tom: Good find! The title was obscure so I renamed that question to make it easier to find next time. The first answer explicitly cites Arch Linux.

Comment: How is it a good find, I specifically said free in my question. And this is NOT a duplicate, the others that have programs that are either command line only unlike gyazo, or are no longer available.

Comment: @MitchWeaver 1) You said "free" after the fact it was marked a dup 2) the other question has free software within it's answers

Answer (score 0):

I know of a program called GifRecorder. It's a simple script that cost $3. It has the following features:

- saves .gif images to your home directory
- HiDPI support
- GIF looping support
- a single executable
- also allows for MP4 and H.264 video recording

## [GifRecorder](https://procedural.github.io/post/GifRecorder/) ($3)

[image: GifRecorder]